# Black shadows are appearing on my transparent render

Tags: shaders, transparency

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Transparent Image]
[image: Shading Properties]

I'm having a problem. When I created a group of leaves from a transparent image and went to viewport shading to preview it, These black shadows appeared around them. I had the same issue earlier with a different transparent model and I solved it by putting on alpha clip and alpha blend but when I tried the same thing here, it didn't work.

​

I googled my problem and one of the solutions was to put the Transparency in Render Properties --> Light Paths to 32 but the black shadows are still there. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: hello could you please share your file?

Comment: Use an alpha map instead of mixing transparency.

Comment: @moonboots how do I share a file

Comment: Use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BgnNMRex" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BgnNMRex/)

Comment: could you please only share the leaf object, and don't forget to pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources)

Comment: @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=syW7SBwm" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/syW7SBwm/) I don't understand. When I copied the leaf and put it in a new file, the black shadows dissapeared but when I went back to look at the original, the black shadows were still there. I didn't alter it in between, I promise. Tell me if you have the same issue with the original and new one.

Comment: please pack the image, I still can't see any image here

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BlDlsPOJ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BlDlsPOJ/) I really apologize for that. I'm new at Blender which is why I keep missing some stuff. I hope I did it correctly this time. If I didn't, let me know.